# Group two vertically lines of Buttons within <div class="row"> in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to sort two vertical lines of buttons next to each other, if possible with a line between them.

So I made a div element of the class row with three columns within.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>@TextResources.ActiveProcesses</h4>
        @foreach (var process in Model)
        {
            <div class="btn btn-default">@GetString(process.ActionName)</div>
        }
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>@TextResources.AvailableProcesses</h1>
        @foreach (var process in UnusedProcesses)
        {
            <div class="btn btn-default">@GetString(process.ActionName)</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

All Buttons do appear, but next to each other. How can I group them vertically?

I need:

Button | Button

Button | Button

Button |

I get:

Button Button Button | Button Button

Comment: ...the 'Button | Button Button | Button Button |' layout you described is vertical. do you mean horizontally?

Comment: It shows up different than in the editor. They should be aligned underneath each other.

Comment: post the contents of the container div .row as they're rendered client side. it's tough to sort out styling issues while guessing what your server-side code is returning. :)

Comment: This one? .row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

Comment: No, I mean what's returned on the client-side when this code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your buttons the `col-md-12` class:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>@TextResources.ActiveProcesses</h4>
        @foreach (var process in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-12 btn btn-default">@GetString(process.ActionName)</div>
        }
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>@TextResources.AvailableProcesses</h1>
        @foreach (var process in UnusedProcesses)
        {
            <div class="col-md-12 btn btn-default">@GetString(process.ActionName)</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is one solution. I also solved it by using <br> after each button.